# Is there any harm in adding redundant security rules in Windows? (ACL)

Tags: c#, windows, acl

I have .NET code which adds an ACL rule to a file every time it is written to. This is because the write action creates the file if it doesn't exist and the code doesn't know if the file existed prior. Obviously various checks could be added, such as checking existing rules and if the file is new. However this question is a general case question: is there any harm in adding redundant rules?

```
var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(_filePath, AccessControlSections.Access);
var everyone = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-1-0");
fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(
  new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                     AccessControlType.Allow));
File.SetAccessControl(m_FilePath, fileSecurity);
```

I am hoping that Windows ACL is clever enough to see a repeat rule and not make additional records internally.

Comment: As a best practice, it'd be best to avoid repeats

Comment: At the lowest level, the ACL and ACE functions just maintain flat lists and do no checking or deduplication. Fortunately for you the .NET classes do, however, and as such there's no harm in trying to add the same rule again (it just won't get added). It's still a good idea to avoid calling `SetAccessControl` needlessly, because this has concurrency issues if someone else also wants to modify security, and it produces redundant audit entries if auditing is enabled.

Comment: There is, of course, also the simple fact that continuously overwriting security even if the file already existed is probably a dickish thing to do if someone explicitly changed the security to something else. If they have the permission and go to the trouble of doing so, they presumably would like their changes to *stick*, without the application overriding this constantly. (Reasonable exceptions exist, like SQL Server "fixing" the security of database files, to ensure those remain secure.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the Windows API does have a higher level that handles merging ACEs, canonical ordering, and inheritance: get the DACL with [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645), merge in new entries with [`SetEntriesInAcl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379576), and set the DACL back with [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379579).

Comment: @eryksun: Fair enough. It's been literal ages since I've actually had a look at the APIs, and I've fortunately never actually had to use them myself. I do remember scary articles from back in the day that had reams of code to do even the simplest things with security descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I would mark as accepted if I could ;)

Comment: @eryksun where did you get this information from regarding the win API implementation? Please share :)